# I want the the database query result to output the record of last seven days (referral_users )

Tags: mysql, wordpress

```
get_results( "SELECT u.ID, 
            ( SELECT meta_value FROM " . $wpdb -> prefix . "usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'first_name' AND user_id = u.ID ) AS firstname, 
           ( SELECT meta_value FROM " . $wpdb -> prefix . "usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'last_name' AND user_id = u.ID ) AS lastname,
           ( SELECT COUNT( user_id ) FROM " . $wpdb -> prefix . "usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'user_parent' AND meta_value = u.ID ) AS referral_users 
              FROM
        " . $wpdb -> prefix . "users AS u 
              WHERE 
        ( SELECT COUNT( user_id ) FROM " . $wpdb -> prefix . "usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'user_parent' AND meta_value = u.ID ) > 0 
              ORDER BY referral_users DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0" );
```

Comment: what is your column name that is for storing date-time ?

Comment: i do not have the column for date-time but this is a simpler form of what i need,

Comment: SELECT COUNT( user_id ) FROM wpcg_usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'user_parent' AND meta_value = 1

Comment: i want the count to give result of past seven days

Comment: its a wordpress query, perhaps wordpress have a default column for registration date

Comment: i found it      user_registered however this is the format of the information i found in it

2017-10-14 20:57:49